# ./Car: error while loading shared libraries: /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.so: internal error

Tags: arm, qt

I am in the ubuntu server cross-compiled QT program, in the compilation project, and there is no error, but I am in the cross-compiled program transplanted to ARM, prompting an error

The file mentioned in the error, I have copied from ubuntu to ARM, do not know why there will be an error, but also hope your answer

[image]
This diagram is a version of arm's libopencv core
[image]
This image is the libopencv core version of ubuntu

I used someone else's compiled opencv file and put it directly into ubuntu and arm

Comment: What version of `libopencv_core` is on your cross compiler's host?  Is that the same version as on the ARM destination?  You can't just copy libraries, you must "match" libraries

Comment: Hello, these two versions are the same, both are arm versions, and both are copied from the same folder

Comment: I used someone else's compiled opencv file and put it directly into ubuntu and arm

Comment: As you've now found out, you can't just copy someone else's library unless everything matches.  Remove the "borrowed version", go back to your build-host/cross-compiler and compile libopencv_core from it then tell the makefile for your application to use static linking then copy both your cross-compiled app and cross-compiled library back to the desired destination, i.e. the ARM

Comment: See also: [Static and Dynamic Linking in Operating Systems](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-and-dynamic-linking-in-operating-systems/)